# C++ DLL Header includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, header-files

I am creating a DLL inside Visual Studio.

I have 3 own header files that I includes in the header file of the DLL.
I want to throw away the 3 header files once they are compiled inside the DLL.

I tried many ways to accomplish this but not with good results. When I remove the 3 header files from the project, I get errors that the header files are missing. The DLL is compiled and created.

DLL.h :

```
#ifndef DLL_H
#define DLL_H

#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"

#endif
```

I included the DLL.h in my main.cpp to use the DLL and the header files that are included.

I also created a DLL.cpp but this file is empty.

How do I set up the files or settings inside Visual Studio that the header files can be recognized from the DLL but that the header files are not present?

Comment: Header files are not "included in the DLL". They serve a different purpose entirely. Header files are used by the compiler; the DLL is used by the linker and the runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by "throw away" and why do you want to do that? Header files are part of the source code of most C++ projects. Header files are seen only by the preprocessor. You can choose Generate Preprocessed File in the Properties of your CPP file and inspect the resulting .i file that actually is passed to the compiler. Compiler doesn't know what to do with #include.

Answer (score 1):

If these headers are not relevant to API exported by DLL you shouldn't include them in DLL header file. 
If you really want to do it such way you you can hide them with preprocessor.

```
#ifndef DLL_H
#define DLL_H

// You can set BUILDING_DLL=1 in only DLL project, 
// I assume that you already have such variable to determine 
// whenever to use  __declspec(dllexport) or  __declspec(dllimport)
#if BUILDING_DLL
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
#endif

#endif
```

But I encourage you to verify if it is needed. Will it compile without these headers? If it will you can simply remove them and include only in cpp file. If it will not, you cannot remove them since once you will want to link to DLL compiler must know API and ABI coming from this header. E.g. if there is declared some type that is used as function argument compiler must know this type.

Comment: Okay I will explain my problem better. The 3 header files contain variables that needs to be used by main. In first instance I includes the header files in the main so I could use the variables. Now I wanted to create a DLL so that it needs to be compiled only once and when other users want to use this information, I can send them the DLL instead of the 3 separate header files.

Or is a DLL not the best way to do this?

Comment: Well, that's totally different question. Is that variables or constants though? I miss the big image here. If DLL is supposed to replace headers it sounds like constants, but they are runtime configuration, right? DLL is ok, but I'd suggest wrap these variables with functions, getters and setters. If you need to have variables though you will have to keep headers included in both main and dll, but define them only once in DLL and export. Whenever you change values you just build new DLL and send it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097548/exporting-global-variables-from-dll#3097666)